# Win forms designer not opening a derived form in .NET 6. The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022

Deleting bin and obj folders, cleaning solution, and restarting studio did not help.
Designer does open a base form.
Inherited form (FrmBase) has an empty constructor and no parameters. Some of the derived forms have and some do not have an empty constructor, constructor with or without parameters, the error is the same for all.
FrmBase is in another project.

Update 2022-08-05: when I copy the exact form file with its designer, change the name of the class and it works.  But I don't want to do that for a hundred+ forms in my solution. I also looked at differences in the project file for those forms and there is none.

[image]

The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object.

Instances of this error (1)

1. Hide Call Stack

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.InvisibleEditor..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String filePath, IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Boolean needsSave, Boolean needsUndoDisabled)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.TextManagerAdapter.CreateTextPoint(FileCodeModel fileCodeModel, VirtualTreePoint point)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.InternalElements.AbstractCodeElement.get_StartPoint()
at EnvDTE.CodeClass.get_StartPoint()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.VsCodeDomProvider.Parser.ProcessClass(CodeClass vsClass, CodeNamespace namespace)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.VsCodeDomProvider.Parser.ProcessNamespace(CodeNamespace vsNamespace, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.VsCodeDomProvider.Parser.ProcessFileCodeModel(FileCodeModel fileCodeModel, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.VsCodeDomProvider.Parser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomProvider.Parser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.CodeDomSource.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.CodeDomManager.GetDeclarations()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.PerformServerLoad()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.PerformLoad()

Help with this error

Could not find an associated help topic for this error. Check Windows Forms Design-Time error list

Forum posts about this error

Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

Comment: Some details please and post the stack as text. Which component are you talking about? ToolTip, ErrorProvider? Custom? If the last, how does the non-default constructor look like?

Comment: @dr.null base form is for all forms I have in the project. I even tried creating a new blank base form, attaching it to only a single form that has an empty constructor, derived form has an empty constructor also and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have another .NET Framework project that has those forms linked from .NET6 project. When I just copy the form to .NET Framework project, the problem is resolved.

Comment: This no longer works.